# What should the Django DATABASE settings be in settings.py when you are using Apache2, Python, and Django on Ubuntu 12.04 and MSSQL on another server?

Tags: python, sql-server, django, django-settings

What should the Django DATABASE settings be in settings.py when you are using Apache2, Python, and Django on Ubuntu 12.04 accessing an MS SQL database on another server? Currently my settings are:

```
ENGINE: 'sql_server.pyodbc',
'NAME': 'DatabaseName',
'USER': 'DatabaseUserName',
'PASSWORD':'DatabaseUserPwd',
'HOST':'ServerID\sql2008_r2',
'PORT':'Postnumber', 
'OPTIONS': {'driver': 'FreeTDS', 'host_is_server':True, ''extra_params':"TDS_VERSION-8.0"}
```

Comment: It is the application specific settings. Hence it is in the application settings

Comment: That looks the same as some settings I have been using successfully for one of my projects, except that my HOST value is just the server name - just 'ServerID' rather than 'ServerID\sql2008_r2'.

Comment: Is there any error-message? 
Did you check the Firewall-settings on that windows-server where MSSQL resides?
Is MSSQL Configuration set properly with network-libraries?
And yes and no, use Server-IP-Address but if there is an instance with the name sql2008_r2 you have to use this as netioned.